# Use <form:select> tag with a map

Tags: forms, spring, spring-mvc

Is there a way to map the data inside a map to  tag?
I have a map `Map<String, Integer>` in my code.
Is there a way to map the option labels to the `String` in the map and the `Integer` to the option values?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [`<form:options>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.options) tag supports what you want right out of the box, using the `items` attribute. You can do something like this:

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> states = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
states.put(1, "Alabama");
states.put(2, "Alaska");
states.put(3, "Arizona");
states.put(4, "Arkansas");
states.put(5, "California");
```

And so on. Then in your form:

```
<form:select path="state">
    <form:options items="${states}" />
</form:select>
```

That will be rendered to something like:

```
<select name="state">
    <option value="1">Alabama</option>
    <option value="2">Alaska</option>
    <option value="3">Arizona</option>
    <option value="4">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="5">California</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed too!  :D

Answer (score 9):

See the Spring [form:select](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.select) and [form:options](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.option) documentation. Use `items`, `itemValue`, and `itemLabel` as needed.

```
<form:select path="myFormVariable">
    <form:option value="0" label="Select One" />
    <form:options items="${myCollection}" itemValue="propertyToUseAsValue" itemLabel="propertyToUseAsDisplay" />
</form:select>
```

Comment: I believe when using a Map, the `itemValue` and `itemLabel` are not necessary.

Comment: this is use full when i want to use a list of object and want to avoid creating  unnecessary  map.

Comment: This answer is correct when using a java.util.List of objects but *not* with a java.util.Map, which is what the original question was about. When using a Map, you must leave off itemValue and itemLabel. The option's value will be the map's key and the option's label will be the map's value.