# how to put a selectbox and Multiselect box in Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am  doing an application with spring mvc  where i need a static select box and multi select box.i have   previous experience with struts 1.x there i have successfully developed  selectbox and multiselectbox here is the example

```
                             selectbox in struts
                                      <tr>
                                        <td class="removeRightBorder">
                                            <html:select property="call_type"                  multiple="true">
                                                <html:option value="ALL"/>
                                                <html:option value="SMS"/>
                                                <html:option value="VOICE"/>
                                                <html:option value="MMS"/>
                                                <html:option value="GPRS"/>
                                            </html:select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
```

multiselect box

```
                                  <tr>
                                        <td class="removeRightBorder">
                                            <html:select property="call_mode" multiple="true">
                                                <html:option value="ALL"/>
                                                <html:option value="LOCAL"/>
                                                <html:option value="STD"/>
                                                <html:option value="ISD"/>
                                            </html:select>   
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
```

i need these two boxes in spring somebody please help..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Spring `form` taglib you can use the [select](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.select), [options](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.options) or [option](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.option) tags.

There are many tutorials on this. You should have a look at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/) blog post or at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210733/use-formselect-tag-with-a-map) SO question.

Comment: these are the  ways  where data is coming from the data base or a map  but i need to put hard code values there

Comment: Then just hardcode values with the `<option>` tag like this: `<form:option value="ALL" label="All" />`