# java springframework <select> tag

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, select

I am struggling with "SELECT/OPTIONS" tag. I have 2 `ArrayList<<String>>`:  "pNames" and "pIds".  Form should display "pNames", while the values returned to controller should be "pIds".  From my spring controller I am passing the following 2 ArrayLists.  How do I implement this in Spring MVC?

```
    ArrayList<String> pIds = pps.getPIds();
    ArrayList<String> pNames = pps.getPNames();
    model.addAttribute("pIds", pIds);
    model.addAttribute("pNames", pNames);
```

```
    <form:select id="pps" name="pps" path="pIds" multiple="multiple">
       <form:options items="${pIds}" itemValue="${pNames}" itemLabel="${pNames}"/>
    </form:select>
```

Above code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your Lists to a `Map<String, String>`. Then you can add the map to your model and you only need to do:

```
<form:select path="pIds">
    <form:options items="${mapName}" />
</form:select>
```

For more information, please checkout this question: [Use <form:select> tag with a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210733/use-formselect-tag-with-a-map)

Comment: This is a much better approach, if it's a possibility for your case, because it means you don't need to worry about keeping the two lists in the correct order.